# How can I easily generate 10,000+ records for testing?

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I am trying to stress-test an Apex class that takes all of the Contacts in the org, modifies the addresses, then updates the records. I want to create thousands of Contacts and/or Accounts to test with. I made a trigger that can make up to 100 records at a time, but that's not enough. Is there an easy/fast way to do this?

Comment: You do not really need to do that. Trigger chunk records in chunks of 200 so all you need to properly test your code is 200 records. (Minimalist view) There are other things to take into consideration of course. If it is a batch then I believe the chunk size defaults to 2000, with the triggers further chunking it in to 200.

Comment: What Eric said...but don't use a trigger, use execute anonymous, e.g. for (Integer i = 0; i < 500; i++) {//create record //add to collection for insertion} //insert collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Execute Anonymous. However, you will not be able to do more than 10k records in one DML shot, so you might want to run this multiple times. You might want to change the starting/ending values of "a" so your names don't duplicate.

```
List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
for (Integer a = 0; a <5000; a++) {
  accts.add(new Account(Name = 'Test ' + a));
}

insert accts;

List<Contact> conts = new List<Contact>();
for (Integer a = 0; a< 5000; a++) {
  conts.add(new Contact(AccountId = accts[0].id, LastName = 'Test ' + a));
}

insert conts;
```